# Alternative to getimageuri() for google charts calendar

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, google-visualization

I have a calender chart being created using the `Google Charts API`. I have been looking for a way to print the chart as `png` and I haven't been able to find a good working answer.

Since `getImageURI()` is not a method listed for Calendar Charts so I can't use the Printing PNG Charts guidelines on Google Developer either.

Update:

I was able to find [this tutorial](http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html) which has been helpful in downloading the image but the issue is that the filename of the file being downloaded is the image bytecode and the solution offered on [this page by greenthumb](http://greenethumb.com/article/1429/user-friendly-image-saving-from-the-canvas/) doesn't work properly. Using the package downloaded from CanvasSaver GitHub which was linked to on the greenthumb page, the file downloaded upon clicking the save image button is the `saveme.php` file and not the actual image. I have tried placing `obj_close();` before `echo $decoded;` in `saveme.php` but that hasn't helped solve the issue either.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately google charts only allow core charts and geocharts currently to be printed with getImageURI()

Comment: Do you know of any alternatives ? Perhaps using JS/jQuery ?

Comment: Not sure, maybe this helps: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/21/convert-svg-to-png/

Comment: Looks promising. I'll post if it works out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final script that's working for me with an example calendar Google chart. The file which will be downloaded is named "calendar.png" and it's set using html download attribute for links. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re3nf6op/). I am still struggling to find a way to change the background of the image created from transparent to white.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/canvg.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function getImgData(chartContainer) {
                var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
                var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
                var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
                var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
                canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);

                canvas.setAttribute(
                    'style',
                    'position: absolute; ' +
                    'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px; ' +
                    'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
                doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
                canvg(canvas, svg);
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
                return imgData;
            }

            function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
                var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);
                var link = document.getElementById('linker');
                link.href = imgData;
                link.download = "calendar.png";
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {
                packages: ["corechart", "treemap", "geochart", "calendar"]
            });
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                //Calendar
                var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                dataTable.addColumn({
                    type: 'date',
                    id: 'Date'
                });
                dataTable.addColumn({
                    type: 'number',
                    id: 'Won/Loss'
                });
                dataTable.addRows([
                    [new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032],
                    [new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024],
                    [new Date(2012, 3, 15), 38024],
                    [new Date(2012, 3, 16), 38108],
                    [new Date(2012, 3, 17), 38229],
                    // Many rows omitted for brevity.
                    [new Date(2013, 9, 4), 38177],
                    [new Date(2013, 9, 5), 38705],
                    [new Date(2013, 9, 12), 38210],
                    [new Date(2013, 9, 13), 38029],
                    [new Date(2013, 9, 19), 38823],
                    [new Date(2013, 9, 23), 38345],
                    [new Date(2013, 9, 24), 38436],
                    [new Date(2013, 9, 30), 38447]
                ]);

                var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

                var options = {
                    title: "Red Sox Attendance",
                    height: 350,
                };

                chart.draw(dataTable, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
<a title="Background is transparent." id="linker" onclick="saveAsImg(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));"><button>Save as PNG Image</button></a>

        <div id="calendar_basic" style="width: 1000px; height: 350px;"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: When I click on the 'Save as PNG button' in the JSFiddle reference provided, the resulting image shows up blank.

Comment: Thats weird, I just tried it and I can see the image fine. Have you tried it on a different computer?

Comment: Just realized: Doesn't work in Firefox (43.0.4) but it worked in Chrome.